# Is it possible to open a car's door lock with smartphone?

Tags: locks, remote-start

Smartphones like samsung galaxy s6 edge have Infrared lens at the top which helps in turning on many devices (like Aircondition etc). What if we copy the wave that is transmitted by the original remote of car in smartphone and use it to open the car. Why theives don't do that?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Most key fobs are radio frequency (RF) devices. Your smartphone's IR port (do they really have these on there?) isn't going to do you much good in this instance.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The spec says it has one. https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s6_edge-7079.php. An app to change TV channels using your phone would be useful for example. But unlike radio frequencies, Infrared only works with a direct line of sight from the transmitter to the receiver, so it would be fairly useless as a car remote.

Comment: @alephzero the phone might have one, but if the car does not use that technology it's like having a bike pump on a wooden wheeled horse cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cars typically do not use IR to unlock - they use radio waves instead. So this won't work.

However, attackers have been successfully using versions of this attack which uses RF, for quite some time now.

In the early days, the attacker would use RF jamming to stop your keyfob locking the car. Simple, but reasonably effective against folks who wouldn't check their car was locked.

Not long after that attackers moved to recording the RF signal and replaying it - so manufacturers developed systems that would not respond to a **replay** attack, and instead would require a new code to be transmitted each time.

A current attack is a **relay** attack - where they get the code from your key which is inside your house and transmitting it directly to a device held next to your car. See [this carlock.co article](https://www.carlock.co/blog/en/2019/01/04/keyless-car-theft-how-thieves-are-using-hacking-to-steal-your-car/) for more info.